# fontDescriptorWithSymbolicTraits method returns a new font descriptor reference in a different font family instead of same font family on iOS13

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode11, ios13

fontDescriptorWithSymbolicTraits method returns a new font descriptor reference in a different font family instead of same font family on iOS13

```
@interface ViewController ()
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [ViewController bold];
}


+(UIFont *)systemFontCaption
{
    return [UIFont systemFontOfSize:20.0f weight:UIFontWeightRegular];
}

+(UIFont*)bold
{
    UIFont *font = [ViewController systemFontCaption];

    UIFontDescriptor *fontDescriptor = [UIFontDescriptor fontDescriptorWithName:font.fontName size:font.pointSize];
    UIFontDescriptor *styleDescriptor = [fontDescriptor fontDescriptorWithSymbolicTraits:[fontDescriptor symbolicTraits] | UIFontDescriptorTraitBold];
    UIFont *boldFont = [UIFont fontWithDescriptor:styleDescriptor size:font.pointSize];
    return  boldFont;
}
```

Expected Results:

Bold font should be in the same font family i.e SFUI-Regular

Actual Results:

Bold font is in different font family i.e TimesNewRoman

Comment: Had the exact same problem, with even simpler code: [UIFont fontWithName:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12.].fontName size:12.] returns TimeNewRoman font instead of a San Francisco on iOS 13. This code used to work.... since iOS 3! Do you have any idea what's happening?

Comment: Apple responded with > "This is caused by improper use of a system font name. Rather than creating a new font descriptor by name, use - [UIFont fontDescriptor]"

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Apple has a bug with the font for attributed string since...iOS 13 beta!!! But this issue is shown only on Xcode 11+.

[Open radar](https://openradar.appspot.com/6153065)

The best solution is to do not use system font, but use font name exactly.